# Ireport generet in Yii Framework?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to call Ireport In yii framework. please Give me example or link.

```
            $AReport = new IReport('report/reginvoice.jrxml');

            $AReport->parameters = array("SRF_STUDENT_ID"=>'ABC/RG9');

            $AReport->execute();
```

i used this but not working.

Comment: I suggest you to use jasperserver as report server and use a wrapper for JasperServer api in Php. I have used this wrapper: yii-jasper, for Yii 1.1.x and it worked as I expected http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiijasper/. With this method you Will keep separate responsabilities from .jrxml (java and jasperserver) and your Php webapp

Comment: please can i give me video Link. i looked for this but not understood.

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [JasperServer as report server](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-jasperreports-server) and use a wrapper for JasperServer api in your Yii webapp.

JasperServer api works on any backend technology (not only PHP).

With this approach you will keep separate responsabilities:

- Report creation/design/modifications: IReports, JasperStudio or any .jrxml generator
- Report generation/execution/service/repository: JasperServer
- Report visualization/use/consume to end user: JasperServer wrapper for your web application backend.

I have used this JasperServer wrapper with Yii 1.1.x and JasperServer 5.5.x: [yii-jasper](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiijasper). It worked as I expected.